# Merge two objects in TypeScript without key existence check

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

I want to merge two objects. Take default as a base model and replace all values from next object. But TypeScript throws an error for my types.

I have this object:

```
const grades = {
  "grade": {
    "level": 1,
    "state": 1,
    "grade": "B"
  },
  "level": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Level 1"
  }
}
```

And I have a type for them:

```
export type UserLGType = typeof grades
export type GradeType = typeof grades.grade
```

Now on somewhere else I declare a variable like this:

```
const x: UserLGType = grades // get all values as default
```

Now, My issue is that, I get some of the values from database. Lets assume this is grade from db:

```
const gradesFromDB: any = { "level": 2 }
```

As you can see its `any` and only contains `level` as `2`

Lets merge over default values:

```
x.grade = {...x.grade, gradesFromDB}
```

### Expected result:

```
   {
      "grade": {
        "level": 2, // see here..
        "state": 1,
        "grade": "B"
      },
      "level": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Level 1"
      }
    }
```

### Actual result:

```
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'gradesFromDB' does not exist in type '{ "level": number; "state": number; "grade": string; }'.
```

**See demo here**: https://repl.it/repls/BusyAccomplishedData

Now, how can i merge those two objects? I can do loop but it is going to be a large dataset so, is there a fast and safe way of doing this? Just get the defaults, and change values from database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do this:

```
x.grade = {...x.grade, ...gradesFromDB}
```

The spread operator on gradesFromDB extracts the properties into the new object. As you have it, you're assigning some property "gradesFromDB" on the new object that value.

But, you should stop doing these short hand type declarations and write actual interfaces:

```
export interface GradeType {
  level: number;
  state: number;
  grade: string; // maybe better like: 'A'|'B'|'C' etc 
}

export interface UserLGType {
  grade: GradeType;
  level: {
    id: number;
    name: string;
  }
}
```

Then use them to type things:

```
const DEFAULT_GRADE: UserLGType = {
  "grade": {
    "level": 1,
    "state": 1,
    "grade": "B"
  },
  "level": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Level 1"
  }
}

const gradesFromDB: Partial<GradeType> = { "level": 2 }
```

Comment: Got my answer at first line, however, I will follow what you said and define them then use as Partial. Thank you!

Comment: yea, the rest was just extra advice on good practices. You only need the first part to fix your issue.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, will definitely go with that.